# Internet explorer jquery + SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, svg

i have a little script on jQuery that is suposed to get the value of certain SVG element and store it on a hidden input. Finally, it adds a class that changes the SVG element opacity.

The problem is that it doesn't work at all on IExplore (no wonder). Here's the script:

```
    $(function() { 
        $("#diagnostic svg g").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log($(this));

            $("#location").val($(this).attr("id"));


            $(this).parent().find("g").each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr("active");
            });
            $(this).attr("active","active");
        });
    });
```

and the css definitions:

```
#diagnostico svg g { opacity: 0; }
#diagnostico svg g:hover,
#diagnostico svg g[active="active"] { opacity: 1; }
```

is there any way to fix it for IE?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Older versions have minimal (if any) support for SVG. Although it may not be ideal, you may want to consider converting your SVGs and implementing your vectors in Rafael.js - also older versions of Internet Explorer choke on console.log (that may be an additional issue). Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne I'm using IE9, i've read that there's no previous support. Here's a minified version: http://jsfiddle.net/s7k4T/

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne apparently it was the console.log interfering, thanks for the insight :-)

Comment: Shoot, can I add this as an "answer" and have you upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer has minimal support for console.log